# With org-babel, how to name the results of a function call and reuse them

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In `org-mode`, I am trying to define a function, a variable, and then assigning to another variable the result of the function call on the first variable. However, then it seems that I cannot use this new variable in subsequent functions calls.

Inlining the function calls does work, but affecting the value to a variable first would allow for faster debug in case something goes wrong in the first function call, and to avoid duplicating potentially expensive computations.

MWE: (use `(require 'ob-emacs-lisp)` if needed)

```
#+name: square
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=3
  (message (format "%s" (* x x)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: square
: 9

#+name: value
: 45

#+name: squaredvalue
#+call: square(x=value)

#+RESULTS: squaredvalue
: 2025

Now I try to reuse this value: 

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var res=squaredvalue
  (message res)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: nil

Inlined calls do work:    

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var res=square(value)
  (message res)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2025
```

Expanding the second code block shows:

```el
(let ((res (quote "nil")))
  (message res))
```

What am I missing?

(This has been tested on emacs 24.3.1, 24.4 and 24.5, using org 8.2.10)

Comment: something to do with Babel of Library I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Explicitly add new `#+name:` above the `#+results:` block.

> **Note:** Updated your code from `(message res)` to  `(message (format "%s" res))` to prevent a `Wrong type argument: stringp, 2025` from causing additional confusion.

```
#+name: square
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=3 
  (message (format "%s" (* x x)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: square
: 9

#+name: value
: 45

#+name: squaredvalue
#+call: square(x=value)

#+name: squaredvalue-results
#+RESULTS: squaredvalue
: 2025

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var res=squaredvalue
   (message (format "%s" res))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: nil


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var res=squaredvalue-results
 (message (format "%s" res)) 
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2025
```

> **Tested using**
> GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.10.9)
> Org-Mode Version: 8.2.10

Comment: Ok, that's definitely the simplest solution to date. In this case, there is actually no need for the `#+name:` before the `#+call:` line, so it doesn't add any bookkeeping to the process : just name the results instead of the definition. Maybe it doesn't feel as natural as it could, but at least that's not a work-around begging for an alternative solution.

Comment: This is nice (+1). I tried it and it works with org-mode 8.2.7c. Interesting that a search of the info documentation of Org Mode for `-result` returns no results. Please add a note that naming the call is required and that the name of the result must be the name of the call suffixed by `-result`. At least that is what I noted. (If one misses to name the call the next re-evaluation will add a new result ignoring the existing named result.

Comment: @Tobias - Just to clarify, `-result` is just a naming convention I used for this example. If you're explicitly looking for the results of a source block then add `()` to the name when passing the name as a variable to another  block or inside a noweb reference.

Comment: Looks that the only requirement is that the `#+call` is named. The name of the result can be chosen arbitrary. If the call is not named an additional unnamed result line is generated by the call.

Comment: Is there any section in the manual that describes that behaviour?

Comment: @Tobias If the call is not named, the next evaluation will produce a new results block, because the old block (with a results name) will not correspond to the (unnamed) call block. But subsequent evaluations won't produce new blocks. If you add a name to this results block (with `#+name`, not `#+results`) it still works.

Comment: @Melioratus The type error is indeed additional confusion, I guess `org-babel` auto-types the variables passed this way. On the other hand, note that with the last example in the question, there was no type error, implying that results of inlined calls are treated differently (probably handled as string unconditionally) than variable references.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `:post`-routine which outputs the result as `:name`. Call your babel-block with this post routine and put the result into a drawer.
In the following example this post routine is named `asValue`.

```
#+name: asValue
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var name="last" :var val=0 :results drawer
(format "#+NAME: %s\n: %s" name val)
#+end_src

#+name: square
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=3
(message "Running square")
(* x x)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: square
: 9

#+NAME: value
: 45

#+call: square(value) :post asValue(name="squaredValue",val=*this*) :results drawer

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
#+NAME: squaredValue
: 2025
:END:

Now I try to reuse this value: 

#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :var res=squaredValue
  (format "Re-used value: %s" res)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Re-used value: 2025
```

Another way to avoid re-calculation of code blocks is the `:cache` header argument. If this is set to `yes` the code block and its arguments are checked for changes and if there are no changes the previous result is used without re-evaluation of the source code block.

```
* Running of source blocks with caching

#+name: square
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :cache yes :var x=4
(message "Running square")
(* x x)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS[31bcff57ec9977f9b237fdc62ab18b1378b8c646]: square
: 16

#+NAME: value
: 40

#+name: squaredValue
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :cache yes :var x=square(x=value)
x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS[f90a5856e446c3120f7e91c4b77959598078526e]: squaredValue
: 1600

Now I try to reuse this value: 

#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :var res=squaredValue
  (format "Re-used value: %s" res)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Re-used value: 1600

Re-trying with call:

#+NAME: value2
: 20

#+NAME: squaredResult
#+call: square(x=value2) :cache yes

#+RESULTS[2f7c47d4c609a1a49ce00b4696afb7b5a5517b97]: squaredResult
: 400

The last version gives the following error with org-mode 8.2.4 in emacs 24.3.1.
(I do not know why.)

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)
  org-babel-set-current-result-hash("94ef10d9192a0be25e46238df4cf05389ff69040")
  org-babel-lob-execute(("square(x=value2)" ":cache yes" 0 "squaredResult"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hacks! It seems that both solutions work, but we're somewhat getting away with the "just try it, it'll work the way you expect it to" philosophy of org. If it turns out that there is no other solution, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @T.Verron I think the second solution (`:cache yes`) is the standard solution. It is also described in the org-manual (see section 14.8.2.16 `:cache'). It is a pity that it does not smoothly work with `#+call`. I think this is a bug. The first solution works with `#+call` and also has the advantage that it completely decouples code blocks. Even if you edit the first code block and try the second one the first one is not evaluated. (Depending on the task that may be an advantage or an disatvantage. You just have to keep it in mind.)

Comment: I was tired last night, I didn't notice... Even if there was no error at evaluation of the last block, would it really work better than the ones I wrote in the question? After all, the problem is not that it reevaluates the call for each reference (it would be a problem too, and then yes, cache would be the solution), but that I cannot reference it at all.

Comment: @T.Verron Kyle Meyer is right. The changes http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=commitdiff;h=1877652ce0234cf333fa103b5ada08fbf5946ab1 did not make it yet into the trunk. The newest version is here: http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ob-ref.el;hb=HEAD. But, maybe, there are incompatible changes...

Comment: @T.Verron Above I meant "stable release" and not "trunk". Sorry about that. You can see my answer 1 as workaround for the missing feature.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you just need to upgrade your Org mode.  This works on my end (current developmental version of Org) and in general should work as of the tag `release_8.3beta`.  Below is the commit that I think fixes the problem you're describing.

```
commit 1877652ce0234cf333fa103b5ada08fbf5946ab1
Date:   Wed Nov 13 11:42:40 2013 -0700

    allow reference to named call lines

    * lisp/ob-ref.el (org-babel-ref-resolve): Look for call lines when
      resolving references.
```

---

Aside from loading Org from the git repo, another option for running a newer version is to [install the ELPA package](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

Comment: Well, I may not use the development version, but that does not mean I have not updated since 2013. I am not *that* late. `;)` To be precise, my `org-version` is 8.2.10. I have editted the question with this information, where it should have been in the first place.

Comment: Ooops, sorry about the misinformation.  That should be the commit, but it isn't contained in 8.2.10.

Comment: Would you know where I can find a discussion about this commit?

Comment: If a discussion about it existed, it would most likely be on the Org mode list, but I didn't find one by searching, and there isn't one referenced in the commit message, so there may not be one.